# Javascript: Array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help from you guys!

This is my JS code:

```js
var myArray[2] = "Hi";
```

It says: "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement".

I dont't see where the hell I forgot an ";" in the easiest code ever.

Comment: Have you defined `myArray = []` yet?

Comment: javascript arrays doesn't work that way - have a look up this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: What is myArray ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valid array in JS:

```
var myArray = new Array(3); // 3 - count of elements
myArray[2] = 'Hi';  // third element has a value "Hi"
```

Read more about arrays [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the array first

```js
var myArray = Array();
myArray[2] = 'hi';
console.log(myArray )
```

Answer (score 0):

Its either a *var*iable declaration:

```
 var myArray = "Hi";
```

Or you set a property:

```
myArray[2] = "Hi";
```

Comment: Best answer in context, but... why are all answers so simplistic? Then they don't need to answer

Comment: @hand1cloud i answer to help the OP. I just needed 10 seconds to do so. And another 5 to flag as dupe...

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your aray before using it. Try this:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[2] = "Hi";
```

But then you have a gap at the beginning! Beware of that!